# Biometric device stopped working in windows 8.1 after update and also after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, drivers, biometrics

The biometric device in my HP laptop stopped working after I updated Windows 8.1 **.** After I updated to Windows 10, the problem persisted.

My biometric device is from Validity Sensors, Inc.

Any solution will be welcomed.

Comment: Please give more details

Comment: "or update of 8.1" - What?  Have you installed drivers for the device which have specific support for Windows 10?

Comment: @Ramhound There is no driver for that device in windows 10. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: @Private The device worked fine in windows 8.1. But stopped working when i updated the window. Now i have windows 10 installed and it still does not work. I have installed all the drivers.

Comment: If there isn't a driver that supports Windows 10 then it cannot be used on a machine running Windows 10.

Comment: @azae What biometric device are you using? The manufacurer, The model id, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Private Its a fingerprint recognition sensor by Validity Sensors, Inc.

Comment: @Ramhound In Device manager, it says its installed.

Comment: @azae http://support.lenovo.com/in/en/downloads/ds103635

Comment: @Private My laptop is HP. Will it still work? I will give it a try.

Comment: @azae I got the link from here: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Validity-Fingerprint-Common-Driver-for-Windows-10/td-p/5171912

Comment: If it works, please comment, I will write the answer.

Comment: So basically, the author didn't have the drivers installed, I asked that question 2 hours ago.

Comment: @Ramhound: The OP had some driver installed, just not the one that works.  I guess that must make a difference.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

This problem persists in HP laptops as found [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Validity-Fingerprint-Common-Driver-for-Windows-10/td-p/5171912).

You can fix this problem by downloading the drivers for the biometric device from [this site](http://support.lenovo.com/in/en/downloads/ds103635).